# How i can handle all Unity UI animations on single update function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, unity-ui

I'm making my own `animation` library I want to handle all animation logic within a single `Update` function.

**Here is the code**

```
[RequireComponent (typeof(RectTransform))]
public class UIMotion : MonoBehaviour
{

    public enum MoveDirType
    {
        XDir,
        YDir
    }

    [SerializeField]   private   Spring   spring;
    [SerializeField]   private   float    target;
    [SerializeField]   private   MoveDirType  moveDir;
    
    private   Vector2         initialPos;
    private   RectTransform   rect;
    
    private void Awake  ()
    {
        rect       =  GetComponent <RectTransform> ();
        initialPos =  rect.anchoredPosition;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        float    springValue   =  spring.GetSpringValue (target, Time.smoothDeltaTime);
        switch (moveDir)
        {
            case MoveDirType.XDir:
              rect.anchoredPosition   =  new Vector2 (springValue, rect.anchoredPosition.y);
            break;
            case MoveDirType.YDir:
               rect.anchoredPosition  =  new Vector2 (rect.anchoredPosition.x, springValue);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    void OnDisable()
    {
        rect.anchoredPosition = initialPos;   
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code. Every `UIMotion` Component will have its own `Update` function after animation it will be unless to run `Update` code that's why I took this approach but there are some problems in this approach.

**My Approach**

```
public class AnimationThread : MonoBehaviour
{
   public List <Action> animationActions; // action = UIMotion Update Function
   
   private void Update ()
   {
      foreach (Action action in animationActions) action.Invoke ();
   }
}
```

This code is work for starting animation but I have another scenario also like playing animation on a panel open or on button click.

**Note:** You might suggest just disable the component when the animation is finished but in my case, I'm using [springs](https://gist.github.com/FleshMobProductions/7b523b81d7595e685410be11b24aac3f) and I'm unable to figure out where exactly the animation is ending.

> How can I handle these all animations from one update function `OR` or is there any way to find where the animation is ending

**Spring Code:**

```
public class Spring 
{
    public   float   equilibriumPosition;
    public   float   dampingRatio;
    public   float   angularFrequency;

    internal float   value;
    internal float   velocity;  

    public Spring () {}

    public float GetSpringValue (float targetValue, float deltaTime)
    {
        SpringMotion.CalcDampedSimpleHarmonicMotion(
            ref value, 
            ref velocity,
            targetValue,
            deltaTime,
            angularFrequency,
            dampingRatio
        );

        return value;
    }
}
```

**Resources**

[**Reference**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFOAipGJGA0&t=576s)

[**Full Source Code**](https://gist.github.com/FleshMobProductions/7b523b81d7595e685410be11b24aac3f)

[**Article**](https://www.ryanjuckett.com/damped-springs/)

**Exactly Want to achieve something like** [**this**](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php#tweenerSequenceSettings)

---

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: I don't quite follow you ... what you currently have is a separate `Update` method for each instance of your components ... you ask us how to reinvent an entire library like DoTween ...?

Comment: @derHugo I just wondering how much cost each update function will take. `In Short` I want to optimize it